# Jquery allow only float 2 digit before and after dot

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

i have to allow only number like these:

- 2 or 45 (from 0 to 99)
- 2.50 or 35.75 (2 digits before dot and 2 digits after)

Someone can help me? I could limit only int in this way:

```
$('#valueSconto').on('input', function () {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: You can use: `/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`

Comment: are you trying to replace or match?

Comment: as you can see, i want to replace

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: `.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')`

Comment: ok @AvinashRaj that work, but i need also to allow only decimal minor 100 with 2 decimal number, like 99.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `input` `maxlength` to `5` ; utilizing `.val(function(index, val))` ; `RegExp` `/\d{3}|[^\d{2}\.]|^\./`

```js
$("#valueSconto").on("input", function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/\d{3}|[^\d{2}\.]|^\./g, "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" id="valueSconto" maxlength="5" />
```